# php imagick - read image from base64

Tags: php, base64, imagick

I am manipulating images with js, and I'd like to save these transformed images. I'm posting this data with ajax:

```
image : canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
```

This way, I get the base64 code for the image, but I can't find a way to read it with Imagick.

This is my process:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$decoded = base64_decode($_POST['image']);
$img->readimageblob($decoded);
```

But this fails:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/360' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test/save.php:7
Stack trace:

#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/test/save.php(7): Imagick->readimageblob('u?Z?f?{??z?????...')

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured out.

I had to remove the `data:image/png;base64,` part from the posted string, and then imagick could interpret it as blob.

Answer (score 5):

readImageBlob — Reads image from a binary string : http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php

```
$base64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN....";

$imageBlob = base64_decode($base64);

$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob($imageBlob);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick;
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 3):

Read this url;--

[PHP-Imagemagick image display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087569/php-imagemagick-image-display)

or try it:-

```
$thumbnail = $img->getImageBlob();
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($contents)."' />";
```