# Create PDF thumbnail with Imagick and write to file

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to create a pdf thumbnail with Imagick and save it on the server in the same location as the pdf.  The code below works fine as is.  The problem is that I don't want to echo the image.  But if I remove the echo statement, the resulting jpg file contains errors and is unreadable.  How can I create the thumbnail and write to a file without sending it to the browser?

```
$pdfThumb = new \imagick();
$pdfThumb->setResolution(10, 10);
$pdfThumb->readImage($filePath . $fileName . $fileExt . '[0]');
$pdfThumb->setImageFormat('jpg');
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $pdfThumb;
$fp = fopen($filePath . $fileName . '.jpg', "x");
$pdfThumb->writeImageFile($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

[DaGhostman Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1747193/daghostman-dimitrov) provided some helpful code on [#16606642](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087569/php-imagemagick-image-display/16606642#16606642), but it doesn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try:

```
$pdfThumb = new imagick();
$pdfThumb->setResolution(10, 10);
$pdfThumb->readImage($filePath . $fileName . $fileExt . '[0]');
$pdfThumb->setImageFormat('jpg');
$fp = $filePath . $fileName . '.jpg';
$pdfThumb->writeImage($fp);
```

Comment: I get an error: Imagick::writeimagefile() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: Woops that should be writeImage() - I do not use Imagick very often.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Bonzo's answer requires imagick on the webserver. If imagick is not on the webserver you can try to execute imagemagick from the commandline by php command exec():

```
exec('convert -thumbnail  "178^>" -background white -alpha remove -crop 178x178+0+0 my_pdf.pdf[0] my_pdf.png')
```

And if you like to convert all pdfs in one step from same folder where your script is located try this:

```
exec('for f in *.pdf; do convert -thumbnail  "178^>" -background white -alpha remove -crop 178x178+0+0 "$f"[0] "${f%.pdf}.png"; done');
```

In this examples I create a png thumbnail 178x178 pixel from the first page (my_pdf.pdf[0] the 0 means first pdf page).